# What is the exact date that `transfer` method as an alias will be deprecated on Westend and Polkadot mainnet

Tags: westend, releases

I read the release notes for version 0.9.42, which was published on May 4, and noticed that the `transfer` method has been changed to `transfer_allow_death` method, and `transfer` will now serve as an alias for the new method `transfer_allow_death`. The pull request's description stated that the `transfer` method will still remain but its naming is now DEPRECATED, and ecosystem tools should transition to using `transfer_allow_death` within 3 months, after which the `transfer` alias will be removed. I understood that the transfer method will be deprecated three months from the publication date of the release note, but I am uncertain about the starting point for counting those three months until deprecation. Could someone please provide me with the exact date when the `transfer` method will be deprecated　on Westend and Polkadot Mainnet?

Release Note: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.42

Pull Request: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12951

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to give an exact date of when the `transfer` method will be completely removed and hence become unavailable.
What you mentioned in your question is all correct and you can try to calculate 3 months after the date of the v0.9.42 release but it will all be approximations and many things can happen that can change those dates.

I would recommend to follow the below approach to check when `transfer` will be removed completely :

- Follow up regularly with the progress of this issue  [[Deprecation] Remove deprecated `Balances::transfer` #148](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/148)

  - There are corresponding tasks in the description of the issue so you can check the progress
  - There is this also a linked open [PR](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/1226) where you can also check part of the progress
- After all the PRs related to this issue are completed/merged, you should check in which release they are included.
- Double check the complete deprecation is mentioned in the release notes of the corresponding release (this is also one of the tasks in the above issue).
- Then for this change to happen/take effect in Polkadot mainnet there is also the step of a referenda that needs to be submitted/voted/passed and enacted for the corresponding runtime upgrade. In the proposal you can usually check the enactment date so there you will have the exact date of when it will be removed from Polkadot.
- In Westend this last step is not included so as soon as the release (which includes the change) is published then you should expect to see also the change in Westend some time soon. Since Westend is a testnet the upgrade happens earlier there so that the community/teams have time to test and check the changes.

Having mentioned all of the above, one last thought regarding this :

- Instead of trying to calculate and estimate the exact date of the `transfer` method deprecation, why not replace already all the instances of `transfer` method in your code/product with the new `transfer_allow_death` ?