# when will `‘Balances::transfer' will be removed` take into effect on main-net?

Tags: polkadot-js, runtime, runtime-upgrade

In this link [`Balances::transfer` will be removed](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/9854) it say 'transfer' is deprecated.
I have experienced this change on test-net and fixed my Dapp after got failure report.

But when does it take into effect on main-net?

Because some reason I can not perform this upgrade on my own and need to notify others to do it in advance. Where I can get this kind of information or know the current stage that API changes are at?

The polkadot API specs is less stable than ETH's, I have run into this kinds of things many times, very annoying and it would make life easier if I can take action before changes happen on chain.

Comment: FYI, this already happened for Kusama ecosystem with the 1.1.0 runtime upgrade, and will follow in the next couple of weeks in Polkadot (when the runtime upgrade is enacted).

Answer (score 2):

You can check this [answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/9778/234) to know the general steps/process of the deprecation of the `transfer` method.

Since August (when the above answer was posted), the following updates have occured :

- The mentioned [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/148) was closed
- The mentioned [PR](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/1226) was merged
- The above PR was included in the Polkadot release [v1.2.0](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/releases/tag/polkadot-v1.2.0)

So the last step for you is to check when the proposals will be submitted (one proposal for Kusama and the corresponding proposal for Polkadot) to upgrade the runtimes to v1.2.0. As soon as the proposals are passed and enacted then you will see the changes in main net or as we call it the corresponding Relay chain (Kusama and Polkadot) also.

Having said that and as mentioned in the answer from August, instead of trying to calculate and estimate the exact date of the
`transfer` method deprecation, I would recommend to just replace already all the instances of `transfer` method in your code/product with the new `transfer_allow_death`. The same is recommended [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/1226#issuecomment-1709609875) :

> *The recommendation is to migrate to the new `force_set_balance` and
> `transfer_allow_death` ASAP*